# Effective interest rate for mortgage loan

Tags: mortgage, loans, interest-rate, mortgage-rate

I'm currently deciding between taking loan with down payment and no down payment. To get behind the idea, I read a case study from a finance textbook.

I get the basic math and understand concept of present value, but couldn't understand how some numbers came up while analysing it. Here is the case:

---

Mortgage loan is $100,000, with 30-year duration. You can choose either to pay down payment or not. If you don't, annual interest rate is 12%, if you do take the offer of paying $2,000 (2% discount point off initial $100,000), you get 11.5% annual interest rate.

**Case 1.** No down payment, annual interest rate is 12%, therefore, monthly is 12%/12 = 1%. Compounding monthly:

```
Effective annual rate =  (1.01)^12 - 1 = 0.1268, which is = 12.68%
```

**Case 2.** Down payment  = $2,000. (so, now we owe $100,000-$2,000 = $98,000) Interest rate at 11.5%, therefore, monthly should be 11.5%/12 = 0.9583%.

In this case, using finance calculator, [monthly payment would be $990.29](http://www.bankrate.com/calculators/mortgages/loan-calculator.aspx?loanAmount=100000&years=30.000&terms=360&interestRate=11.500&loanStartDate=19%20Aug%202017&email=&lightbox=true&show=false&showRt=true&prods=1&monthlyAdditionalAmount=0&yearlyAdditionalAmount=0&yearlyPaymentMonth=%20Aug%20&oneTimeAdditionalPayment=0&oneTimeAdditionalPaymentInMY=%20Sep%202017&ic_id=mtg_loan_calc_calculate_btn)

Now, this is where the confusion begins. My monthly rate as what I manually calculated is 0.9583%, **BUT** the book states it should be **0.9804%**.

---

Hence, **Question:** How and why does the monthly rate turn out to be **0.9804%**??

If we reverse the calculation with that rate, it turns out we actually get higher interest rate; 0.9804% * 12 = 11.76%, higher than initial 11.5%.

Quote/screenshot from the book:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The 2 'points' for which you pay 2000$ will _buy you the lower interest rate_. They are not a down payment, you still owe the full amount.

Comment: @Aganju thanks for the comment. Agreed. I misunderstood the concept. Feel free to edit my question. That being said, how would the calculation using 'points' affect the interest rate? As you can see, the book suggest 0.9804%. That's 11.76% annual. Higher than what I would be paying at 11.5% (0.9583%)..

Comment: The 2K is interest. If you payoff the loan before the breakeven point the interest rate is very high. But it will always be larger then 11.5%

Comment: The image shows a footnote **1** after the **0.9804%** figure: does that say anything relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the $2000 downpayment and interest rate of 11.5% nominal compounded monthly the [monthly payments would be $970.49](http://www.bankrate.com/calculators/mortgages/loan-calculator.aspx?loanAmount=98000&years=30.000&terms=360&interestRate=11.500&loanStartDate=19+Aug+2017&email=&lightbox=true&show=false&showRt=true&prods=1&monthlyAdditionalAmount=0&yearlyAdditionalAmount=0&yearlyPaymentMonth=+Aug+&oneTimeAdditionalPayment=0&oneTimeAdditionalPaymentInMY=+Sep+2017&ic_id=mtg_loan_calc_calculate_btn)

As you state, that is a monthly rate of 0.9583%

**Edit**

With the new information, taking the standard loan equation

```
s = (d - d (1 + r)^-n)/r
```

where

```
s is the loan principal
d is the periodic payment
r is the periodic interest rate
n is the number of periods
```

Let

```
s = 100000
r = 0.115/12 = 0.00958333
n = 30*12 = 360

d = (r (1 + r)^n s)/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 990.291
```

Now setting `s = 98000`, with `d = 990.291` solve for `r`

```
r = 0.980354 %
```

[image]

Comment: yes. But in the book, it states that the monthly rate is 0.9804%. Wondering if I missed something the textbook assumed.

Comment: @Mr.Slow Can you quote more of the book, or include an image, because that rate seems unrelated to anything else you're mentioned.

Comment: hey Chris, up there, I uploaded the screenshot of the case. second paragraph from the bottom.

Comment: Hey Chris, just a thought for you. There is no down payment. The $2000 is  "points". To the OP - points or money paid to the bank or lender in exchange for a bit of a lower interest rate on the loan. I will let Chris take it from here

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, My bad, you're right, just realised they are points which means in both cases actually there are no money down. However, wouldn't the rates be unaffected? I believe that monthly rate should be 0.9583% (11.5% annual)? If you look at the screenshot, the book suggest higher interest rate, 0.9804% (11.76%). How does it get to that number?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen knows his stuff, and I'll yield to him on this one. The question is now clear, and really, one good answer would be fine.